# Trying to Understand Windows Controls and Message Handling in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I understand the basic process of creating windows using the `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()` functions and the processing of messages from Windows in the `WndProc()` functions. My question is more related to the creation of child windows for controls such as buttons, textboxes, combo boxes, etc. that appear on the main window created. Does each control displayed on the main window require a separate `WndProc()` in order to process the actions appropriately, or can they be handled via the main window `WndProc()`? Also, is it necessary to destroy each of the child windows used for the controls separately from destroying the main window or are they destroyed when the main window is? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: An honorable task, but I highly recommend using a GUI Framework instead.  Most frameworks wrap around the Windows API, so you don't need to understand it.

Comment: FYI, Windows is an event-driven operating system.  Windows uses a message scheme notify objects (windows) that an event occurred.  The message is usually sent to the object that has "the focus".  So, yes, you'll need a message processing loop in all the windows (at least that is my understanding).

Comment: I highly recommend purchasing "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzold.  It has been the authoritive book about writing applications for Windows operating system.